# jqgrid with an information panel for each column makes grid to show scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqgrid

We are using jquery grid, the last column of the grid should have link. By clicking the link a new panel should appear which gives more info.

So we used a formatter, which generates a `hidden div` and `link`. The problem is that for last rows, the information panel makes the grid to have the scroll bar.

Correct
[image]

Incorrect
[image]

I made a very simple test at http://jsfiddle.net/9a3uaL5h/. as you see clicking the `click me` will make the grid to scroll.

The formatter is as:

```
function panelFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
  return '<div id="sample" style="zindex:1000; height: 200px; display:none;position:absolute; 
          background-color:red" > More Info </div>
          <a onclick=$("#sample").show()>click me</a> ';
}
```

How can I fix that the panel be displayed on to of grid without scroll bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how looks your real code, but the jsfiddle demo isn't good. In any way your main problem: the `<div>` which you use to show an additional information has `<td>` element as the parent. It's the main reason of your problem. You should append the div to the body before displaying it to prevent the clipping on the grid.

Additionally I would recommend you

- to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.4 instead of old jqGrid 4.6
- don't place fix `id="sample"` in the divs to prevent id duplicate errors
- use `beforeSelectRow` callback instead of `onclick` attribute. The `beforeSelectRow` callback will be called inside of `click` handler bound to the *grid* (`<table>`). It will be called because of [event bubbling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Event_flow). The `tagret` property of the event object gives us full incormation about the clicked element.

The modified demo could be about the following

```
function panelFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return '<div name="sample" style="z-index:2000; height: 200px; display:none;position:absolute; background-color:red"> More Info </div> <a>click me</a>';
}

...
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    ...
    beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
        var $td = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow>td"),
            colName = $td.length < 0 ?
                null :
                $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam").colModel[$td[0].cellIndex].name;
        if (colName === "status" && e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "a") {
            // <a> in the "status" column is clicked
            $td.find("div[name=sample]")
                .appendTo("body")
                .position({
                    of: $td,
                    at: "left bottom",
                    my: "left bottom+" + $td.height()
                })
                .show();
        }
    }
});
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/9a3uaL5h/1/

**UPDATED:** One can use jQuery Events in the same way like callbacks. For example, one can use the event `jqGridBeforeSelectRow` instead of `beforeSelectRow` callback. The code will be

```
$("#grid").bind("jqGridBeforeSelectRow", function (event, rowid, e) {
    var $td = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow>td"),
        colName = $td.length < 0 ?
        null :
    $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam").colModel[$td[0].cellIndex].name;
    if (colName === "status" && e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "a") {
        // <a> in the "status" column is clicked
        $td.find("div[name=sample]")
            .appendTo("body")
            .position({
            of: $td,
            at: "left bottom",
            my: "left bottom+" + $td.height()
        })
            .show();
    }
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/9a3uaL5h/2/. By the way one can use `jQuery.bind` (or better `jQuery.on`) **before** the grid is created from the empty `<table id="grid"></table>`. See http://jsfiddle.net/9a3uaL5h/3/

Comment: Dear Oleg, thanks! It was very useful, as my jqGrid is generated with `struts 2 jquery grid tag` I can not easily deal with`beforeSelectRow`, is it possible that I can solve this in my `formatter` method ?!

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi: You are welcome! You can do the same using jQuery Events (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_triggered_events_new_in_v4.3.2)) instead of callbacks. The first parameter of the event is not really helpful, but the next parameters correspond the parameters of the callback. For example the demo from my answer can be changed to the following: http://jsfiddle.net/9a3uaL5h/2/

Comment: exactly what I was looking for :)