# I want to get the edit dialog on click of a link..I have attached the code

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

Here is the ColModel:

```
{name: "FirstName", index: "FirstName", width: 100, sortable: true,      editable:true, formatter: GetRow}             

function GetRow(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
     return "<a href='#' class='GetLink'>" + cellvalue + "</a>";
}
$('.GetLink').click(function (rowid) {
     var row = $('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
     $('#grid').jqGrid('editGridRow', row, { recreateForm: true, closeAfterEdit: true, closeOnEscape: true, reloadAfterSubmit: false });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code has some disadvantages. I would recommend you to use `formatter: "actions"` with the option `formatoptions: { editformbutton: true }` instead of custom formatter to create edit/delete buttons (see [the old documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types), which describes the options of the formatter, for example `delbutton: false`, which remove Delete button) in every row of the grid. [The old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35295971/315935) describes the approach more detailed and provides [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick_.htm), which demonstrates the usage of `formatter: "actions"`.

If you would do prefer to use custom formatter, then you could use `<span>` instead of `<a>`:

```js
return "<span class='GetLink'>" + cellvalue + "</span>";
```

where

```css
.GetLink { text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer; }
```

Instead of usage `$('.GetLink').click`, which register *separate* click-handler for every hiperlink, I'd recommend you to use *one* click-handler on the grid. jqGrid register already such click-handler and allows to use your custom actions with respect of `beforeSelectRow` callback. It saves memory of the web browser and allows to make binding once instead of reapplying binding after every reloading of the grid. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537512/315935) for more details.

Other answers, which could be helpful for you: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40220736/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40192416/315935).

Comment: @Oleg...Thanks for your suggestion and time...One more problem is      when the edit-dialog opens I get the cell name which i modified as a link appended with "<span class='GetLink'>Cellvalue</span>";

Can you give a solution to get only cell value in the edit dialog

Comment: @Supreeth: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean, but I guess that you use `editable:true` in the column with the custom formatter. It's typically, that one never need to edit the column which contains the link. You should remove `editable:true` or use `editable:false`. One uses typically the properties `sortable: false, search: false, editable: false, viewable: false, hidedlg: true` in columns, which has custom formatter.

Comment: @Supreeth: If you do need to *edit* the text inside of the link then you should provide **unformatter** (the `unformat` callback) in the column. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting). The unformatter get *the editable part* from the custom formatted cell.